Blazor editform displays required message on autopopulated fields
I'm not new to ASP.NET or C#, but I am brand new to Blazor and Entity Framework.
I've got a small form that consists of four fields: "SmockId", "FName", "LName", and "Service". One of the requirements was that the user should only have to fill in the SmockId, click the search button, and it will fill in the FName and LName fields automatically from the database. Those two fields are also disabled because they only want the database values in there. Then they'd just need to select a value from the Service dropdown. The form worked great, so I moved on to validation. I filled in the Model with the desired Annotations and error Messages. However, when I tested the form, I get the "Required" validation message on FName and LName even though they are populated correctly.
At this point I'm assuming it has something to do with the fact that they are auto-populated instead of manual input from the user. I haven't had any success finding what I'm doing wrong online, soooo hopefully Stack Overflow to the rescue...
Form markup and code:
<EditForm Model="@addSmockModel" OnValidSubmit="AddSmock">
    <DataAnnotationsValidator />
    <div class="container-fluid">            
        <div class="row border border-1 rounded p-3">
            <h5 class="text-secondary"><strong>Smock Checkout</strong></h5>
            <div class="col-lg-3">
                <label for="smockid">Smock Id</label>
                <div class="input-group">
                    <InputNumber id="smockid" @bind-Value="addSmockModel.SmockId" class="form-control form-control-lg" />
                    <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" @onclick="FindSmock">
                        <span class="bi bi-search" aria-hidden="false"></span> Search
                    </button>
                    <button class="btn btn-lg btn-warning" @onclick="ClearForm">
                        <span class="bi bi-x-lg" aria-hidden="false"></span> Clear
                    </button>
                </div>
                <ValidationMessage For="@(() => addSmockModel.SmockId)" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3">
                <label for="fname">First Name</label>
                <InputText id="fname" @bind-Value="addSmockModel.FName" disabled class="form-control form-control-lg" />
                <ValidationMessage For="@(() => addSmockModel.FName)" />                       
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3">
                <label for="lname">Last Name</label>
                <InputText id="lname" @bind-Value="addSmockModel.LName" disabled class="form-control form-control-lg" />
                <ValidationMessage For="@(() => addSmockModel.LName)" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3">
                <label for="service">Service</label>
                <div class="input-group">
                    <InputSelect id="service" @bind-Value="addSmockModel.Service" class="form-select form-select-lg">
                        <option value="" disabled selected>--Select--</option>
                        <option value="Clean">Clean</option>
                        <option value="Repair">Repair</option>
                        <option value="Clean/Repair">Clean+Repair</option>
                    </InputSelect>                           
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary">
                        <span class="bi bi-plus-circle" aria-hidden="false"></span> Checkout
                    </button>                               
                </div>
                <ValidationMessage For="@(() => addSmockModel.Service)" />
            </div>                
        </div>
    </div>
</EditForm>

@code
{
    private List<Smock>? smocks;
    private List<User>? user;
    private Smock addSmockModel = new();

    [CascadingParameter]
    public HttpContext? HttpContext { get; set; }

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {        
        await base.OnInitializedAsync();
        await LoadSmocks();
    }

    private async Task LoadSmocks()
    {
        smocks = await dbContext.Smocks.ToListAsync();
    }

    private async Task FindSmock()
    {
        var smockId = addSmockModel.SmockId;

        if (smockId > 0)
        {
            user = await dbContext.Users.Where(x => x.SmockId == smockId).ToListAsync();

            foreach (var record in user)
            {
                addSmockModel.FName = record.FName;
                addSmockModel.LName = record.LName;
                addSmockModel.SmockId = record.SmockId;
            }
        }   
    }

    private async Task AddSmock()
    {
        addSmockModel.CheckedOut = "True";
        await dbContext.Smocks.AddAsync(addSmockModel);
        await dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
        await LoadSmocks();
        addSmockModel = new();
    }

    private async Task EditSmock(Smock smock)
    {        
        dbContext.Update(smock);
        await dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
        await LoadSmocks();
    }

    private async Task DeleteSmock(Smock smock)
    {
        bool confirmed = await JsRuntime.InvokeAsync<bool>("confirm", "Are you sure?");

        if (confirmed)
        {
            dbContext.Remove(smock);
            await dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
            await LoadSmocks();
        }       
    }

    private void ClearForm()
    {
        addSmockModel = new();
    }
}

Smock model class:
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace SmockTrackerApp.Models.Entities
{
    [Table("Smocks")]
    public class Smock
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        [Column("Id")]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Column("SmockId")]
        [Range(1, int.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "Required")]
        public int SmockId { get; set; }

        [Column("FName")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required")]
        [MaxLength(50)]
        public string? FName { get; set; }

        [Column("LName")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required")]
        [MaxLength(50)]
        public string? LName { get; set; }

        [Column("Service")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required")]       
        public string? Service { get; set; }

        [Column("CheckedOut")]
        public string? CheckedOut { get; set; }        
    }
}


If the fields are autocompleted, why do you need validation on the fields in the first place?

because if the user fills in the SmockId but doesn't click the search button and fills in the Service field, they could submit a record with no first name or last name.

Also, just because they enter a value in the Smock Id field doesn't mean that Smock Id is in the database yet.
